# Error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

Tags: python, django, string, unicode

I am currently working on a Calendar in python django web framework. I am trying to print something and raising the following error:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

I have seen people with similar problems but not with 'long' and a solution that works.... 
Traceback:

```
> Internal Server Error: /tande/holiday/ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line
> 149, in get_response
>     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line
> 147, in get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
> line 23, in _wrapped_view
>     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ryoung/Documents/Database/prodman/tande/views.py", line 83, in
> holiday
>     cal = HolidayCalendar(my_holidays).formatmonth(year, month)   File "/Users/ryoung/Documents/Database/prodman/tande/views.py", line 397,
> in __init__
>     print holiday   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line
> 237, in __repr__
>     return repr(data)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line
> 467, in __repr__
>     u = six.text_type(self) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

Here is my code:

```
class HolidayCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

    def __init__(self, holiday):
        super(HolidayCalendar, self).__init__()
        self.holiday = self.holiday_days(holiday)
        print holiday
        # for something in holiday:
        #     print something

    def holiday_days(self, holiday):
            field = lambda holiday: holiday.start_date.day
            return dict(
            [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(holiday, field)]
            )
```

I am trying to see what self.holiday is setting as... I tried a for loop aswell because I thought it would be a list of items and it raised the same error.
Here is the view that calls the above

```
@login_required
def holiday(request):
    # get persons username
    # get month and year today
    date_today = datetime.now()
    year = date_today.year
    month = date_today.month
    # get holiday objects in the current month
    my_holidays = Holiday.objects.order_by('start_date').filter(
        Q(start_date__year=year, start_date__month=month) | Q(end_date__year=year, end_date__month=month)
    )
    cal = HolidayCalendar(my_holidays).formatmonth(year, month)

    # forms... render template...etc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Edit made above :)

Comment: The problem seems to be in your `Holyday` model's `__str__` or `__unicode__` method. Those methods should return resp. a string or unicode object, it looks like it's returning a long (possibly the pk - wild guess...).

Comment: Ah yes you're right I had `def __unicode__ (self):
  return self.id`
I've changed it to description now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your Holyday model's **str** or **unicode** method. Those methods should return resp. a string or unicode object, it looks like it's returning a long (possibly the pk - wild guess...)